# ASP.NET C# - Display Embedded Web Objects in Datagrid control

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Im using Visual Studio 2008, on an ASP.NET C# website.  Overall what I want to accomplish is that when an item from a list of items is clicked, a video will display on the same page.  I want this done all in one aspx page, I dont want to create a new page for each video file.  The video files are hosted for me on www.screencast.com.

What I have done is created data-bounded radio list, and a datagrid which is binded to whatever is selected from my radio list.  So when an item from that radio list is clicked, the video will diplay on the page, along with a description of the video and other important info.

What i have dome so far does not display my videos.  Thats why I am here.  I need to know how I can replace one of the fields from my data grid with an embedded web object.

What path do you guys recommend I take to acomplish my goal?

**EDIT**
With JoeRage's suggestion to use Shadowbox.js, Im going to have on my datagrid a simple link that when clicked, a video will display.  My problem is how do I make my hyperlinks get formatted with the following info:

```
<a rel="shadowbox;width=800;height=600" title="Basic Pricebook Training" href="VideoContent/pricebookMgtBasic.swf"><img src="VideoContent/PricebookMgtBasic.gif" alt="" class="border"></a>
```

I know that on a datagrid, i can add a hypertextFeild.  Problem is that even if I use the DataTextDormatString?

Comment: If you still want an answer, it would help if you could post the code you have that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ShawdowBox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/).

Edit: You can use a [TemplateColumn](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addingtemplatecolumnstodatagrid.aspx) to build the desire output.